# Perforce stream copy doesn't seem like the right option

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I'm just getting started on perforce streams and I'm confused about how to handle a pretty basic situation. Say that I have two dev streams each that are working on some specific, unrelated feature. My stream graph looks like this:

[image]

Let's say that I want `main` to have both `dev1` and `dev2` changes but I do not want `dev1` to have `dev2` changes or `dev2` to have `dev1` changes. I can easily copy my `dev1` changes up into `main`. Since since I don't want `dev1` changes in `dev2` I can't merge `main` down into `dev2`. However, if I don't merge from `main` down into `dev2` I will lose my `dev1` changes in `main` when I copy `dev2` up.

How do you get around this? Or is this how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that **copy** is not the right option!

You'll need to **merge** into the mainline from `dev1` and/or `dev2`.  You can't use **copy** effectively in a scenario where you want streams to diverge from each other, since **copy** by definition forces things to be identical.

Note that by default the **copy** operation should automatically detect that you're copying from a stream that has not already **merged** all of the mainline changes, and fail with an error regardless.  (Assuming you're using the stream-aware version of the **copy** command -- if you just tell it "copy this depot path into this other depot path" then it'll merrily overwrite whatever's in the target.)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification. Is it just me or does this seem like a common scenario? They make a big deal about the "tofu scale" and merge down/copy up but it seems like it's not a terribly realistic approach. Maybe as a git guy I'm just not in the Perforce mindset?

Comment: Merge/copy made more sense in the context of older versions of Perforce (like from more than a decade ago) as a way to work around shortcomings of the old base selection engine that would cause you to have to revisit conflict resolutions during back-and-forth merges.  The modern version of the merge logic handles those merges very sanely, though, and will automatically infer when it's appropriate to do a simple copy, so you should never need to do an explicit copy as part of a normal workflow. I haven't ever been a fan of the "copy" command except as a sledgehammer for very specific use cases.